# Problem installing zmq on amazon linux (unable to find uuid)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, uuid, zeromq

I'm trying to put together an AMI on EC2, and am currently stalled on building 0mq.

initially, I got this error while running ./configure

```
checking for uuid_generate in -luuid... no
configure: error: cannot link with -luuid, install uuid-dev.
```

I installed e2fsprogs-devel and linux-utils via yum, which I believe contained the required library, but still got the error above. I subsequently installed uuid-devel with yum and got no further.

Then, I created a link as below:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0 /lib64/libuuid.so
```

and now ./configure completes happily, but I get an error when I run make

```
[...]
CXX    libzmq_la-signaler.lo
CXX    libzmq_la-socket_base.lo
In file included from socket_base.cpp:50:
uuid.hpp:31:23: error: uuid/uuid.h: No such file or directory
In file included from socket_base.cpp:50:
uuid.hpp:92: error: 'uuid_t' in namespace '::' does not name a type
make[2]: *** [libzmq_la-socket_base.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/this/infrastructure/zeromq2-2/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/this/infrastructure/zeromq2-2/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

The following is the beginning of /usr/include/uuid.h, if that's useful.

```
#ifndef __UUID_H__
#define __UUID_H__

/* workaround conflicts with system headers */
#define uuid_t       __vendor_uuid_t
#define uuid_create  __vendor_uuid_create
#define uuid_compare __vendor_uuid_compare
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#undef  uuid_t
#undef  uuid_create
#undef  uuid_compare
```

I'm pretty well stumped at this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ultimately, I satisfied the dependency by running

```
$ yum install uuid-devel
```

also worth noting is that to get libzmq to link into the other programs that needed it down the line (Mongrel2, for example), I had to add the line

```
/usr/local/lib
```

to /etc/ldconfig.so.conf and run

```
$ ldconfig -v | grep zmq
```

(if you don't see an entry for libzmq.so in the output, something's off)

Comment: It is common to need the -devel (or -dev on Debian systems) package when you are building something, as opposed to just installing binaries. These packages are almost always named the same as the binary package with -devel or -dev added onto the name.

Answer (score 19):

As pointed out on https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=576296#c0, use libuuid-devel instead of uuid-devel,

```
$ sudo yum install libuuid-devel
```

This resolved the missing /usr/include/uuid/uuid.h file for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, read the [documentation](http://www.zeromq.org/intro%3aget-the-software) on installing zeromq! :)

i.e.

Make sure that `libtool`, `autoconf`, `automake` are installed.
Check whether uuid-dev package, uuid/e2fsprogs RPM or equivalent on your system is installed.
Unpack the .tar.gz source archive.
Run `./configure`, followed by `make`.
To install ØMQ system-wide run `sudo make install`.
On Linux, run `sudo ldconfig` after installing ØMQ.

As mentioned, on Amazon Linux, you'd install deps by doing:

```
sudo yum install uuid uuid-devel
```

N.B. the instructions also mention the requirement to do:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

after install too.